# How I can get color of specific li in Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

My HTMl file has code:

```
<li id="b1" onclick="myfunc(this)" class="thumbsup fa fa-thumbs-up" ></li>
```

Above code makes a like button whose color changes on click.

Now I want to get its color on form submission so that on php side I can add number of likes in DB accordingly. That is if user clicked this button then it's color changes to grey . So in jquery i want to see if it is grey and then in php increment value in DB accordingly. Not sure how i can retrieve color of li element in jquery.

Please note that user can click button multiple times. like first time on clicking , button turns grey and when clicked again. it turns to its default color and so on...

Comment: How I can do that ? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

As @mplungjan states on the comment you don't need a color to get if it is clicked. You can write an onlick function to send an ajax request to your php file, do the query for the like there and on return you can write a very simple code to color and disable click of the button again.

Like this;

```
myfunc(e){
 $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'yourphpfile.php',
  data:{whatever:youwanttosend},
  success:function(data){
   $('#b1').css('background-color':'green');
  });
}
```

Comment: Issue is that it can be clicked multiple times.like first time on clicking , button turns grey and when clicked again. it turns to its default color and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You do not want the color of the li, you want its state. Toggle the class:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".thumbsup").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('liked'); // every time we click we set or remove
    $(this).next().removeClass('disliked'); // remove from the thumbsdown
  })
  $(".thumbsdown").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('disliked'); // every time we click we set or remve
    $(this).prev().removeClass('liked'); // remove from thumbsup
  })
  $("#save").on("click", function() {
    var liked = $(".liked").length,
        disliked = $(".disliked").length;
    
    console.log(liked,disliked);
    // ajax here - sending liked:0,disliked:0 if nothing clicked
    $.post("savelike.php",{ "liked":liked,"disliked":disliked},function() {
       console.log("saved");
    });
  })
})
```

```css
.liked { background-color:green }
.disliked { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="a1" class="thumbsup fa fa-thumbs-up"></li>
  <li id="a2" class="thumbsdown fa fa-thumbs-down"></li>
</ul>

<button id="save" type="button">Save</button>
```

Original more complex example with more than one like/dislike set

```js
$(function() {
  $(".thumbsup").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('liked'); // every time we click we set or remove
    $(this).next().removeClass('disliked'); // remove from the thumbsdown
  })
  $(".thumbsdown").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('disliked'); // every time we click we set or remve
    $(this).prev().removeClass('liked'); // remove from thumbsup
  })
  $("#count").on("click", function() {
    console.log($(".liked").length,"liked",
                $(".disliked").length,"disliked"); // how many

    // which ones - using http://api.jquery.com/map/
    let likes = $('.thumbsup.liked').map(function(){ // array map
      return this.id; // each ID that is liked
      }).get(); 

    let dislikes = $('.thumbsdown.disliked').map(function(){
      return this.id
      }).get();
    // here are the arrays - use .join(",") to get a list
    console.log(likes.length>0?likes:"No likes", 
             dislikes.length>0?dislikes:"No dislikes")  
  })
})
```

```css
.liked { background-color:green }
.disliked { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="a1" class="thumbsup fa fa-thumbs-up"></li>
  <li id="a2" class="thumbsdown fa fa-thumbs-down"></li>
  <li id="b1" class="thumbsup fa fa-thumbs-up"></li>
  <li id="b2" class="thumbsdown fa fa-thumbs-down"></li>
</ul>

<button id="count" type="button">Count</button>
```

Comment: i think this code is only checking one click. in my code /javascript. it can be clicked multiple times. infact there is dislike button wth every like button as well. Like there is a tag "Good weather" with like and dislike button . like button by default is green and dislike button by defaut is red. if user clicks like button it turns grey. if user clicks again then it becomes green again. also if user has selected like / like is grey and then he selects dislike then like button changes to green and dislike becomes grey.

Comment: My like LIs toggle the class. You can click them on and off

Comment: This is the code i am using to handle like and dislike buttons : <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbsup, .thumbsdown');
Array.from(thumbs).forEach((thumb) =>
{
  thumb.addEventListener('click', function() {
   this.previousElementSibling && this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
    this.nextElementSibling && this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  });
}

);
</script>

Comment: With this code, how i can check in ajax that whether like or dislike any of these are selected by user?

Comment: Please see update. Change the console.log in the count code to do the ajax

Comment: Thank you so much for quick help :) Can you please explain the code bit :)

Comment: Sorry i cant understand your code. and now sure how i will get values in php that whether user selected liked or disliked.

Comment: Instead of `console.log(likes.length>0?likes:"No likes", 
             dislikes.length>0?dislikes:"No dislikes")` you can do `$.post("savelikes.php",{"likes":likes.length>0?likes:"No likes", "dislikes":dislikes.length>0?dislikes:"No dislikes"},function() { console.log("saved") })`

Comment: I didn't get it that why you are counting likes or dislikes ? in my case user logins into his account and either select like or dislike , so it's length would be one and there should be +1 in DB. can you please update code accordingly so that i can understand better

Comment: You did not have enough information in your question or comments that led me to believe there was only ONE like/dislike.

Comment: I am sorry for that if i wasn't able to convey complete info. On my page there are multiple tags like "Good weather" , "Good hygiene " and with all these tags there is like and dislike button. So what user can do is that select either like or dislike with every tag and click submit button on screen. (Also there is a comments field on the screen as well)

Comment: But these tags are optional as well. like when user submit screen then we need to check that if user selected any like/dislike with any tag . now in DB i have all these tags with likeand dislike counts. so on php side i will see for instance that "Good weather" was liked so i will increment its vaue by 1 in DB

Comment: I hope i have conveyed complete info to you now.

Comment: I think I have answered above and beyond. All code you will need is in my answer now. If you want more help, please hire me.

Comment: you keep changing your specifications - now again there are more likes. My first answer would send all data from the page in one go

Comment: i am not changing specifications. You are not trying to understand what i am saying.

Comment: Please note: The original question has ONE LI with a thumbs up. - no thumbs down nor mentioning of any. Then in the first comment to my answer: _infact there is a dislike for each like_ so I added a dislike - then in another comment you say _why you are counting likes or dislikes ? in my case user logins into his account and either select like or dislike , so it's length would be one_ - then a few comments later you say _On my page there are multiple tags like "Good weather" , "Good hygiene "_ - not confusing at all ;)

Comment: Actually my question was quite simple. But what you wrote as code , i didnt know how it will work with rest . so i added more things of screen to clarify.

Comment: appologies for the inconvenience :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use find function of jQuery. 
Suppose you have multiple li under div element than you can try the following code to get all `li` elements which color is grey.

```
$( "div.classname" ).find( "li.thumbsup" ).css( "background-color", "grey " ).
```